# Lambda timeout after 1 second

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout, aws-regions

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html Lambda functions are supposed to timeout after 5 minutes but mine is getting a task timed out after 1 second. It reads a small text file from an S3 bucket, parses it and performs an action.

How can I increase the timeout?

Edit: after moving it to a different region I now get the same problem after a much more generous 3 seconds. I now have another problem which is there's no CloudFront trigger options in the eu-west-1 and eu-west-2 regions which I need to run it.

Comment: What makes you think it's timing out?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the lambda function timeout by 2 ways

1. Use the aws console
2. Use the CLI

**Using AWS Console** open the lambda function and modify the timeout setting over there
[image: AWS Lambda Timeout]

**Using CLI** use the `--timeout` flag to increase the timeout 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html